# Try to copy uint8_t number into uint8_t array with memcpy

Tags: c++, arduino, memcpy

I'm trying to use `memcpy()` to copy a `uint8_t` to a `uint8_t[]` array, but it doesn't work. Here is what I've tried:

```
uint8_t mess[16];
uint8_t my_number = 1;
memcpy(mess, &my_number, sizeof(my_number));
```

When I print my `mess`, I have nothing.

Comment: You set only one element of the array. To output its value use at least the conversion specifier %d. or %hhu

Comment: How do you print `mess`? Code looks good to me

Comment: @Pablo I use `SerialUSB.println(char *)mess)` I'm on Arduino with samd21

Comment: This is equivalent to `mess[0] = my_number;`. Is this the effect you are expecting? Or are you looking for [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset)?

Comment: I've changed the tags for you to something more appropriate.

Comment: @simon I don't know what `SerialUSB.println` expects, but it seems to me, that it expects a `\0`-terminated string. Your code does not do that, `mess` is not `\0`-terminated. If that's the case, then you are invoking UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
SerialUSB.println(char *)mess)
```

`SerialUSB.println` requires a null terminated string, but the below does not initialize the array so the values in the array are indeterminate:

```
uint8_t mess[16];
```

Reading indeterminate vales makes the program have undefined behavior so initialize it:

```
uint8_t mess[16]{}; // now initialized with 0:s
```

Further, `memcpy` is unnecessary here:

```
uint8_t my_number = 1;
memcpy(mess, &my_number, sizeof(my_number));
```

It's the same as

```cpp
mess[0] = my_number;
```

And it's unlikely that you actually wanted the character with value `1` when using `println` since it's an "invisible" character (in ASCII at least), but instead wanted the character `'1'`:

```
mess[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>('1');
```